# JavaScript / case-insensitive

Tags: javascript, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I have this function to filter values in order to implement an auto-complete feature:

```
 store.filter(new Ext.util.Filter({
    filterFn: function (object) {
        var match = false;
        Ext.Object.each(object.data, function (property, value) {
        match = match || value.match(Ext.getCmp('search_input_text').getValue());

        });
        return match;
      }
```

I need it to be case-insensitive so that both upper and lower cases would be the same.

```
value.match(Ext.getCmp('search_input_text').getValue());
```

something like `LIKE` in sql. How can I do that ?

Comment: how about storing the items to compare and executing `.toLowerCase()` on em temporarily, but returning the original one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Regexp have a constructor using string arguments.
2. if you need a boolean result don't use **match**, use **test** instead.

   ```
   store.filter(new Ext.util.Filter({
       filterFn: function (object) {
           var match = false;
           Ext.Object.each(object.data, function (property, value) {
               var filterValue = Ext.getCmp('search_input_text').getValue();  
               var r = new RegExp(filterValue, 'i'); 
               match = match || r.test(value);  
           });
           return match;
       }
    ...
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "ABC"
a = a.toLowerCase();
//a == "abc"
```

Convert both values to lowercase, then compare them. If they're equal letters, regardless of capitalisation, it will return true:

Assuming your `value` is a `String`:

```
var input = Ext.getCmp('search_input_text').getValue();
match = value.toLowerCase().match(input.toLowerCase()) ? input : match;
```

This uses temporary variables to return the value with it's original capitalisation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a case-insensitive search, you can write

```
match = (match.toLowerCase().indexOf("search_input_text") >= 0) ? "search_input_text" : match;
```